# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource when doing a facebook login with Angular

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, facebook, devise

I'm struggling with Facebook login via Angular.js in my Rails App.

```
<li><a ng-click="fb_login()" href="">Login with Facebook</a></li>
```

And on my `UserCtrl`

```
$scope.fb_login = function() {
  user.social_media_login();
}
```

That calls a function on `user.js` service

```
social_media_login: function() {
  return user.submit({method: 'POST', 
                      url: '../users/auth/facebook', 
                      success_message: "You have been logged in."
                    });
}
```

On my backend I have setup `rack-cors` gem, but also added this little piece of code on my `application_controller.rb` (needless to say, that I already went back and forth using only rack-cors or just setting the headers in the application controller)

```
before_filter :cors_preflight_check
before_filter :cors_set_access_control_headers

def cors_set_access_control_headers
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, PUT, DELETE, GET, OPTIONS'
  headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*'
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
end

def cors_preflight_check
  if request.method == :options
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '1728000'
    render :text => '', :content_type => 'text/plain'
  end
end
```

But I get on my chrome console the error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxx&redirect_ur…pe=code&scope=email&state=yyyy. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

The terminal on my app shows the following:

```
Started POST "/users/auth/facebook" for ::1 at 2015-09-07 20:07:35 +0100
I, [2015-09-07T20:07:35.847058 #18719]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Request phase initiated.
```

Comment: you are confusing your server cors settings with facebook.com cors settings. You can't control settings on another domain

Comment: what do you mean I'm setting my server cors with facebook.com?

Comment: the failed request is directly to facebook.com. Any settings on your server are irrelevant

Comment: even when the request is made by the rails app? I thought it was necessary to add a CORS header in that request. But the login with fb was working without angular. Isn't there a way to have this working in development?

Comment: From what I understand, this may work in production, I'm using the https from heroku

Comment: I have no idea how a request to your server is being sent to facebook directly by the browser instead. It is however clear that the browser is making request to directly to facebook which is rejected

Comment: The browser is making a request to the rails app, and then the app make the request to the fb servers

Comment: well that is clearly not what the error is showing

Comment: It makes no sense at all to try and load the Facebook login dialog URL via AJAX. You need to _redirect_ the user to that address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, inspired by [this blog post](http://jbavari.github.io/blog/2014/06/04/handling-angularjs-popups-for-oauth/) I made it working basically changing my angular.js logic

in the `UserCtrl` I changed the fb_login() function as follow:

```
$scope.fb_login = function() {
  var openUrl = '/users/auth/facebook?client_id=' + 487506314749953;
  window.$windowScope = $scope;
  window.open(openUrl, "Authenticate Account", "width=500, height=500")
}
```

this opens up a new tab, as it should, to enter the credentials on your fb account. So in a `MainCtrl` that is the controller of the whole scope of the angular app I inserted this

```
if(window.opener ) {
  window.opener.location.reload(true);
  window.close()
  window.location.reload();
}
```

The idea is to close that tab after the login is made on facebook, and reload the the original tab, in this case to correspond to the new state of the app (the navbar options in my case, are different)

On the backend, in the callback controller, you just need to set a cookie for the current user like so:

```
def facebook
  @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"]) if request.env["omniauth.auth"].present?

  if @user && @user.persisted?
    sign_in @user
    cookies[:uId] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]["uid"]
  else
    session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  end
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

And on the angular, you retrieve the cookie and voilá it's working